# Return first record if end of dataset

Tags: c#, linq

I've been working on `next()` and `previous()` functionality to move from record-to-record on a `IEnumerable<T>` set of data.  The methods I came up with  work perfectly and always return the type as I need - except for the first and last record.  If I look at the last record, I'd like the LINQ to return the first record and if I look at the first record, the previous record will be the last.  Making the movement between records endless.

I currently have these methods, (I've renamed the types for privacy):-

```
private static Teddy _getNext(string code, IEnumerable<Teddy> teddies)
        {
            return teddies.SkipWhile(i => !i.Code.Equals(code.ToUpper())).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        private static Teddy _getPrevious(string code, IEnumerable<Teddy> teddies)
        {
            return teddies.TakeWhile(i => !i.Code.Equals(code.ToUpper())).LastOrDefault();
        }
```

I'd still like the LINQ to return a `Teddy` type - otherwise I get into all sort of bother handling null types. Can anyone assist?

Help appreciated.

Comment: You could try to convert that `IEnumerable` into a `LinkedList`. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static Teddy _getNext(string code, IEnumerable<Teddy> teddies)
{
    return teddies.SkipWhile(i => !i.Code.Equals(code.ToUpper())).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault() 
       ?? teddies.First();
}

private static Teddy _getPrevious(string code, IEnumerable<Teddy> teddies)
{
    return teddies.TakeWhile(i => !i.Code.Equals(code.ToUpper())).LastOrDefault() 
       ?? teddies.Last();
}
```

You could use this. It will throw an exception if you pass in an empty teddies collection, though. Using FirstOrDefault() instead would avoid the throw, but return null, which you stated you didn't want.

The `??` is the null coalesce operator, and will return the right hand value if the left evaluates to null. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I would try this implementation:

```
private static Teddy _getNext(string code, IEnumerable<Teddy> teddies)
{
    return teddies.SkipWhile(i => !i.Code.Equals(code.ToUpper())).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()
        ?? teddies.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

The way this works is that when the `Skip(1)` goes past the end of the input, ensuring that `FirstOrDefault()` returns `null`, the [null-coalescing operator `??`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) takes the first record from `teddies`.

The implementation of `getPrevious` will be a "mirror image" of this, using `LastOrDefault()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: +1 for just as thorough answer. Shame I can't mark 2 as correct. Thanks :)

Comment: @dooburt Note that the two answers are not the same: mine is not going to crash even when `teddies` is empty.

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight, but `teddies` can never be empty because the collection is passed to it.  Still, appreciated :)